# Script to hardware inventory- Solace Appliances

Tags: solace

We have bunch of solace appliance in our environment and I want write a script to collect hardware detail from all of them, is it feasible? More like, I want  “show hardware” command output.

Cheers,

Ram

Answer (score 0):

You can use SEMP to pull that information from each Appliance, you will need to have access to a Mangement Username for each Appliance you need to query for information.

With an http POST call to your appliance you can get that information on an XML response, in this case I'm using curl command to send the POST:

```
> curl -X POST -d @[SEMP_FILE] -u [username:password] http://[APPLIANCE_IP_OR_HOST:ADMIN_PORT]/SEMP
```

Example values:

```
> curl -X POST -d @show-hardware-details.semp -u admin:admin http://10.0.0.102:80/SEMP
```

Where the ***show-hardware-details.semp*** file contains the command you want to send to the Appliance on an XML form:

```
<rpc>
    <show>
        <hardware>
            <details></details>
        </hardware>
    </show>
</rpc>
```

This will return an XML response with all the output you normally get from the ***"show hardware details"*** command on the Solace CLI.

For more details on how SEMP and SEMPv2 work:

https://docs.solace.com/SEMP/SEMP-Get-Started.htm

https://docs.solace.com/SEMP/Using-Legacy-SEMP.htm